# oAuth and Yammer

Tags: node.js, oauth, yammer

I am trying to set up an internal RESTful API using NodeJS that communicates with various social media services. One of the services we use is Yammer. Yammer uses oAuth for validation but they offer a permanent validation token. For some reason I am having issues passing the token when I try to POST. From their docs it appears that all I have to do is post everything in the URL. an example would be

```
POST https://yammer.com/mycompany.com/api/v1/messages.json?body=Testing&access_token=<myAccessToken>
```

When I do this I do not get a response. Is there something I am missing?

I would also like to add that testing GET this way does not work either

```
GET https://yammer.com/mycompany.com/api/v1/messages.json?access_token=<myAccessToken>
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the documentation you are using?

Comment: And when you say "Do not get a response", do you mean the response body is empty? What kind of headers are you getting? What is the status code? 404?

Comment: The body is empty. I got a 406 response. This is when using their sandbox. I go through the process of getting a new token and then permanently authorizing my app. When i make a GET request like the one above it returns that response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Yammer API](https://developer.yammer.com/api/) requires the OAuth data to be in the header. If you look at their example for Getting Data, you'll see the request looks like.

> GET /api/v1/messages/favorites_of/1234 HTTP/1.1
>
> HOST: www.yammer.com
>
> Authorization: OAuth
>   oauth_consumer_key="KsTROcNF1Fx3e1PwA",oauth_token="vlVH7A7DOm9wXuHdv58A",oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",oauth_timestamp="1297383841092",oauth_nonce="1047685618",oauth_verifier="E4F8",oauth_signature="yPsEvDnNPIA8xGCFLvMJ73K0DD9ivMpATJeFOSo%26fSFh9UPkHQ6oRwK5OTne33ltnSnbQ9XrAhA72heg"

The OAuth data is in the Authorization header and not in the URL. The only time you have any OAuth data in the URL is when you do the authorize.

Comment: I have read the documentation and attempted to test that using REST console for chrome and still could not get it to work. I didnt copy and paste their example I used my own key. The reason why I posted the example above is because when I use Yammer's sandbox, they automate the process of including the Auth token in your request. When you make the request they format it like above and do not put it in an auth header. Or at least that is what it appears that they are doing.

Comment: On a request for a resource, the OAuth piece always goes in the header. The request won't work unless it had the authorization done correctly.

Comment: @MarkS. Do you happen to have an example of this in .net? I've been trying to figure out how to send a **POST request** but always get **unauthorized**. My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533355/bearer-token-in-the-oauth-authorization-request-header-for-rest-api-post-call

Comment: Look at the code example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188938/net-httpwebrequest-oauth-401-unauthorized).

Comment: @MarkS. Where do i get the **oauth_consumer_key**, **oauth_timestamp**, **oauth_nonce**, **oauth_verifier** & **oauth_signature** from?? All the yammer docs say is to send a **"Bearer"** and then the yammer token that was found in the json return (access_token) when using the **https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=" & clientID & "&client_secret=" & clientSecret & "&code=" & authorizedToken**. Am i doing it wrong??

Comment: Those field are used in the authorization. When you start requesting data, you need to use the OAuth Bearer as described in the [IETF Bearer draft](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-23).

Comment: @MarkS. mind moving over to my posted question to continue this converstation?

Answer (score 1):

I've created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/946148) where I used the Yammer API to post a status after a build completion through Fabric. Its in Python, but possibly it can point you in the right direction.

I am assuming you got the right Access Token though, as thats critical.

I recommend using [this library](https://github.com/jpatterson/yammer4r/blob/master/bin/yammer_create_oauth_yml.rb) to get the access token, as its pretty simple and easy to use. This will ensure you have the right access token.

Comment: Thank you lobster1234. I unfortunately still "don't get it" I cant even get their sandbox to work. They walk you through getting an access token by putting in your key and then secret, then they generate an authorization link and you paste in the 4 digit code to get a permanent auth token. They then claim to automatically put the auth token in for you and let you make some test API calls. None of them work. However, If I take my session cookie information and dont use their sandbox and just put my cookie info in the header and make the same calls it works fine, so I know the calls are correct.

Comment: @lobster1234 I've just tried your gist but no luck still the same error, any advise ?