# .NET HttpWebRequest oAuth 401 Unauthorized

Tags: .net, vb.net, oauth, httpwebrequest, authorization

I need to consume a web resource from a VB.NET app. I have successfully retrieved the access token and am ready to use it to make calls to the protected resource. However, everytime I call the protected resource I receive a 401 Unauthorized response because the Authorization field has not been added to the header.

Here is my code.

```
WebRequest = DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create(ApiUri), HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Method = "POST"
WebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
WebRequest.ContentLength = Bytes.Length
Dim RequestStream As IO.Stream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream
RequestStream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
RequestStream.Close()
WebRequest.Headers("Authorization") = "OAuth " & _
                                      "oauth_version=""1.0""," & _
                                      "oauth_nonce=""" & Nonce & """," & _
                                      "oauth_timestamp=""" & TimeStamp & """," & _
                                      "oauth_consumer_key=""" & ConsumerKey & """," & _
                                      "oauth_token=""" & Token & """," & _
                                      "oauth_signature_method=""HMAC-SHA1""," & _
                                      "oauth_signature=""" & Signature & """"
WebResponse = DirectCast(WebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

I then monitor the request using Fiddler. All I see in Fiddler is the request with the 401 response as shown below (excluding the bodies).

Request

```
POST ***url*** HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: ***host***
Content-Length: 45
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="***realm***"
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 79
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 01:13:22 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
```

Everywhere I've read on the internet indicates that HttpWebRequest should first challenge the server and receive a 401 response as I'm seeing here. It should then try again with the Authorization field added to the header and get the 200 OK response. This second part doesn't happen. Am I not understanding how this works correctly, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Consider using an existing oAuth library (http://oauth.net/code/).  Doing it by hand will probably drive you insane.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am already using code from that site. I actually have the entire oAuth dance working correctly. That is not the problem. I don't believe the problem is even oAuth related (I just included it in the post for completeness). I believe the issue is related to HttpWebRequest and how it is communicating with the server.

Comment: Well I'm not specifying one in WebRequest, so I believe it just uses some default settings, like what IE uses. Should I be setting WebRequest.Proxy to something?

Comment: Well it certainly won't hurt. "Dim lvWebProxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()" and then "lvWebProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials"

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to add the content using a BinaryWriter, not a Stream.

So instead of this.

```
WebRequest.ContentLength = Bytes.Length
Dim RequestStream As IO.Stream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream
RequestStream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
RequestStream.Close()
```

Do this.

```
Using Writer As New IO.BinaryWriter(WebRequest.GetRequestStream)
    Writer.Write(Bytes)
End Using
```

Comment: I think adding your headers before GetRequestStream will also work.